# avd manager does not show - I am not using eclipse

Tags: android

In OS X I navigate to /tools the execute ./android I do not get the Android SDK and AVD Manager. I only get Android SDK Manager. I am not using eclipse. As I am new I can not post an image but I have added a link to a screen shot. Any ideas?

http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/948/androidsdkmanager.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the Android SDK has reworked the command line options to access the different tools.  The SDK manager and AVD manager are now launched using different parameters to the `android` command:

- `./android sdk` will launch the SDK manager (as will running the command without any parameters)
- `./android avd` will launch the AVD manager

Feel free to type `./android --help` from the command line to get information on all the usage options for the manager tool.

HTH